# Error while creating send handler for WCF Custom Adapter in BizTalk 2016

Tags: adapter, biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-2016

While trying to add the host instances to the WCF Custom Adapter as a send handler I am getting the below error messages.

I tried resetting my password and restarted and that didn't work. Also, I tried to change the domain of my machine and bring it back to the original domain but I was not able to do it because of access issues.

Can someone please suggest why this error is occurring at this stage and how can I resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is resolved now. The actual problem was with the workstation/Computer name. At the time of BizTalk configuration I had only given the workstation/computer name, but instead we should give FQDN (fully qualified domain name) like workstation1.xyzcorp.net while configuring biztalk. This resolved my issue.

Thanks.